# React-admin: How do I center a column while using the <Datagrid>?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-admin

I'm new to `React`.

I am creating a table with `<dataGrid>` and I only want to center the values of the first column, but I've tried several ways and couldn't manage how to do it:

```js
<ArrayField source="bans" reference="bans" >
    <Datagrid style={{ width: '500px' }}>
       <BooleanField
          label="isBanned"
          source="isBanned"
          style={{ width: '100%', alignText:'center'}}
       />
       <ReasonsField
          source="reason"
          label="reason"
          style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}
       />
   </Datagrid>
</ArrayField>
```

This doesn't work unluckily.

Comment: Have you yet tried either options, in the answer?

Comment: @MwamiTovi i used the first option, material ui styling, because it's more sticked to a modern approach

Comment: ok, sounds good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to take note of this:

- `react-admin` bases on `material-ui` to present almost all (if not all) it's components.
- To style the `react-admin` components, you need to make use of the `className` props which exists on all components (inherited from `material-ui`).

You can do this in two basic way as follows:

1. **Material-ui styling:**

```js
import { createStyles, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles(() =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      width: '500px',
    },
    bool: {
      width: '100%',
      textAlign: 'center',
    },
    reason: {
      textAlign: 'center',
    },
  }),
);

export const YourComponent = props => {
   const classes = useStyles();  // initialize the styles

   return (
     <ArrayField source="bans" reference="bans" >
       <Datagrid className={classes.root}>
         <BooleanField label="isBanned" source="isBanned" className={classes.bool} />
         <ReasonsField label="reason" source="reason" className={classes.reason} />
       </Datagrid>
     </ArrayField>
   );
};
```

You can read a bit more about [material-ui styling](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/) to appreciate it's dynamics.

---

2. **Normal CSS styling:**

- Within your `src/index.js`, you probably have something like this or slightly different:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css'; // this is the line of interest (update it to call your CSS file)
 
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

- Within your CSS file (for the case of this example, `src/index.css`)

```css
/* i've used css classes */
.column {
   width: 500px;
}
.centered {
   text-align: center;
}
.wide {
   width: 100%;
}
```

- Within your component (of interest):

```js
import clsx from 'clsx'; // install this "clsx" package - an alternative is "classnames"

export const YourComponent = props => {

   return (
     <ArrayField source="bans" reference="bans" >
       <Datagrid className={clsx('column')}>
         <BooleanField label="isBanned" source="isBanned" className={clsx('centered', 'wide')} />
         <ReasonsField label="reason" source="reason" className={clsx('centered')} />
       </Datagrid>
     </ArrayField>
   );
};
```

If you read more about [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) or [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames), you'll notice that you can even style your component based on some react/javascript logic - quite interesting stuff.

Answer (score 1):

How to do this for the Datagrid component is described in detail here:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#css-api-1
It is suggested to use the properties: headerClassName / cellClassName

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  table: {
    width: '500px', 
  },
  bool: {
    width: '100%',    
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  reason: {
    textAlign: 'center',
  },    
});


const classes = useStyles();
...
<ArrayField source="bans" reference="bans" >
  <Datagrid classes={{ table: classes.table }}>
    <BooleanField
      label="isBanned"
      source="isBanned"        
      headerClassName={classes.bool}
      cellClassName={classes.bool} 
    />
    <ReasonsField
      source="reason"
      label="reason"
      headerClassName={classes.reason}
      cellClassName={classes.reason} 
    />
  </Datagrid>
</ArrayField>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In newer `react-admin` versions, you may simply pass prop `textAlign="center"` to the respective Field component, see https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#textalign